# How to make speed calculation accurate in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, cllocation

I use CLLocation with accuracy of kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation. I am able to calculate the speed accurately. However, there is a 10sec delay in calculation...

For example, when I drive car at from 45mph to 55mph, the device shows 55mph around 10 secs later.

Is there a way we could make it a bit more precise?

Here is the code...

```
- (void)getSpeed 
{
    [self.locMgr startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    double numericSpeed;
    self.location = [locations lastObject];
    numericSpeed = self.location.speed * 3.6 * 0.621371;
}
```

Comment: Added as you instructed. I am not getting any error. It is just that a bit slow...